# How to use data put in an ObservableCollection class?

Tags: c#, collections, observable

I am building a small program in C#. I am new to programming and and can't seem to understand how to do this. 
I have a ObservableCollection class and I only manage to add data to it.

```
 public class Destinations : ObservableCollection<Destination>
{
    public Destinations()
        : base()
     { Add(new Destination("from", "to", distance, total_distance, "no reason"));
...
 Destinations d;
 d = new Destinations();
 destinations.ItemsSource = d;
 d.Add(new Destination(lines[i], lines[i + dim / 2], distance, dist, null));
```

How can I access the information I have put in the collection.
I've searched through the methods and found nothing helpful. 
I'm sure it's my fault but please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ObservableCollection has an Indexer (aka Item property).  Like an array or a list you just supply the index of the element you want to retrieve it....

Destinations d;
 d = new Destinations();
 d.Add(new Destination(lines[i], lines[i + dim / 2], distance, dist, null));

Destination d0 = d[0];

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to retrieve the items you added to the collection? You can use the indexer for that, or enumerate it in a for each, ... What is the problem which you're having?

Also, if you bind the collection to a control (i.e., a list control), the elements of the collection should be bound to the control as well.